# how to break a vector into two in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, pandas

I want to separate the column `code` in A into two columns `name` and `number` in B. Any help would be appreciated.

A:

```
index  code    value
0      wrt_10  10
1      wrt_11  13
2      wrc_16  3
4      wrc_14  5
```

B:

```
index  code    value  name   number
0      wrt_10  10     wrt    10
1      wrt_11  13     wrt    11
2      wrc_16  3      wrc    16     
4      wrc_14  5      wrc    14
```

Comment: What's your data's format ? Plain text ?

Comment: Is '`A`' the contents of an input text file?  If so, you can split the columns on multiple whitespace, and then split the "`code`" field on underscore.  e.g. `value, name = code.split('_')`

Comment: I assume this is a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: Yes it is a pandas DataFrame. I should have mentinoed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pandas `str` methods to split the strings, and expand the splits into columns:

```
df['code'].str.split('_', expand=True)
```

Full example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': range(4),
                   'code': ['wrt_10', 'wrt_11', 'wrt_16', 'wrt_14'],
                   'value': [10, 13, 3, 5]})
split = df['code'].str.split('_', expand=True)
split.columns = ['name', 'number']
print(df.join(split))
#      code  index  value name number
# 0  wrt_10      0     10  wrt     10
# 1  wrt_11      1     13  wrt     11
# 2  wrt_16      2      3  wrt     16
# 3  wrt_14      3      5  wrt     14
```